# Constructing function - f(x,y) for the given minimums (Python)

Tags: python, optimization

### Problem Statement:

I need to construct a function f(x,y) in which there're 3 minimums. 2 local and 1 global which are written below.

> Locals are: z = f(0.2,0.3) = 0.7 | z = f(0.6,0.8) = 0.8
>
> Global is: z = f(0.85,0.5) = 0.6

---

## What I've tried so far

I've tried Polynomial regression to construct features that estimate the given minimum points. However, an estimated function z = f(x,y) just going through all the given minimum points without considering them as minimums. I need an approach by means of which I can construct a function that has 3 minimums that are mentioned above. I'd be more than happy if you could provide a code snippet of your approach. As a programming language, I use Python.

## Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

degree = 6


def func(x1, x2):
    arr = []
    for i in range(degree, 0, -1):
        arr.append(x1 ** i)

    for i in range(degree, 0, -1):
        arr.append(x2 ** i)

    arr.append(1)

    return np.array(arr)


def der_func(x1, x2):
    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []
    for i in range(degree - 1, -1, -1):  
        arr1.append((i + 1) * x1 ** i)  

    for i in range(degree + 1):
        arr1.append(0)

    for i in range(degree):
        arr2.append(0)

    for i in range(degree - 1, -1, -1):
        arr2.append((i + 1) * x2 ** i)

    arr2.append(0)

    return np.array([arr1, arr2])


given_x = np.array([[0.2, 0.3],
                    [0.6, 0.8],
                    [0.85, 0.5]])

given_y = np.array([0.7, 0.8, 0.6])

data_x = []
data_y = []

for i in range(len(given_x)):
    x1x2 = given_x[i]

    data_x.append(func(x1x2[0], x1x2[1]))
    data_y.append(given_y[i])

    if i < 3: # in case there's more than 3 data point in given_x
        data_x.append(der_func(x1x2[0], x1x2[1])[0])
        data_y.append(0)

        data_x.append(der_func(x1x2[0], x1x2[1])[1])
        data_y.append(0)

data_x = np.array(data_x)
data_y = np.array(data_y)

w = np.linalg.inv(data_x.T @ data_x) @ data_x.T @ data_y
pred_y = data_x @ w

cost = np.mean((data_y - pred_y) ** 2)
print("Cost | ", cost)

#######################################

X = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
Y = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = np.zeros(np.shape(X))
for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(X[0])):
        Z[i, j] = np.array([func(X[i, j], Y[i, j])]) @ w

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 150)
ax.scatter(given_x[:3, 0], given_x[:3, 1], given_y[:3])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you provide 1) information on your data, how do they look like? How are they organized?, etc., and 2) what code did you try so far?

Comment: @Leevo I added what you requested...

Comment: This doesn't seem on-topic at this site.  Why not math.SE?

Comment: Thank you. What is not completely clear, is: what data are you using? What kind of functions are you working on?

Comment: Do you care if the function is differentiable?

Comment: Do you need exactly 2 local minima or can it have a lot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go is to define functions that are non-zero only near your 'minimal' points, and add them. The goal is to avoid overlap, such that a function associated with a point won't modify the value of your global function around other points.

```
import numpy as np

def func0(x1):
    lim = 0.01
    dist = x1*x1
    if dist<lim:
        value = np.exp(-dist/(lim-dist))
    else: 
        value = 0
    return value
```

That will give you a 1D function with nice properties (value 1 at 0, 0 outside the neigborhood of 0) :

```
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)
z = np.array([func0(i) for i in x])
Z = z.reshape(1000)

plt.plot(Z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Modify it to get a 2 D function centered in (a,b) :

```
def func(x1,x2):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    lim = 0.01
    dist = (x1-a)*(x1-a) + (x2-b)*(x2-b)
    if dist<lim:
        value = np.exp(-dist/(lim-dist))
    else: 
        value = 0
    return value
```

This will give you a 2d function :

```
x = y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
z = np.array([func(i,j) for j in y for i in x])
Z = z.reshape(100, 100)

x, x = np.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.imshow(Z,extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Then build the threes functions associated with your points.

```
def func1(x1,x2):
    a = 0.2
    b = 0.3
    lim = 0.01
    dist = (x1-a)*(x1-a) + (x2-b)*(x2-b)
    if dist<lim:
        value = np.exp(-dist/(lim-dist))
    else: 
        value = 0
    return value

def func2(x1,x2):
    a = 0.6
    b = 0.8
    lim = 0.01
    dist = (x1-a)*(x1-a) + (x2-b)*(x2-b)
    if dist<lim:
        value = np.exp(-dist/(lim-dist))
    else: 
        value = 0
    return value

def func3(x1,x2):
    a = 0.85
    b = 0.5
    lim = 0.01
    dist = (x1-a)*(x1-a) + (x2-b)*(x2-b)
    if dist<lim:
        value = np.exp(-dist/(lim-dist))
    else: 
        value = 0
    return value
```

And add them (up to coefficients that determine the value on points of interest) to form a global function :

```
def global_func(x,y):
    return 1-0.3*func1(x,y)-0.2*func2(x,y)-0.4*func3(x,y)
```

This will give you :

```
x = y = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
z = np.array([global_func(i,j) for j in y for i in x])
Z = z.reshape(1000, 1000)

x, x = np.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.imshow(Z,extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Finally you can check that :

```
print(global_func(0.2,0.3))
print(global_func(0.6,0.8))
print(global_func(0.85,0.5))
```

returns :

```
0.7
0.8
0.6
```

You have a continuous function with all expected properties by construction.

If you are unhappy with it being constant on a lot of the domain, you can modify the individual functions so that they don't stop at the limit with :

```
value = np.exp(-dist)
```

And in your global function, determine which 'minimal' point is the nearest and only apply a function of the form 1-coef * funci based on which point is nearest. This way the individual functions won't overlap and thus won't modify value of the global function around other 'minimal' points.

Comment: Someone asked for the continuity of the function. Yep I think it is, that's why the exponent depend on the distance limit, to make it 0 at the limit instead of just cutting the function. I think you can consider the 1D problem. My limit composition game might be a bit rusty but as dist approach from below lim, -dist/(lim-dist) tend to $-\infty$, and its exponential tend to 0, from above it is constant equal to 0. I would not be surprised to be disproved spectularly tho.

Answer (score -2):

Since you have the exact specifications, you can directly hard-code the answers:

```py
def f(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    "Deterministically return the value of z."
    if (x == 0.85) and (y == 0.5):
        return 0.6 # Global minimum 
    elif (x == 0.2) and (y == 0.3):
        return 0.7 # Local minimum
    elif (x == 0.6) and (y == 0.8):
        return 0.8 # Local minimum
    else: 
        return 0.9 # Not a minimum
```

Answer (score -3):

Add as additional constraint that first derivative is 0, and that its bigger/smaller than all the values on the interval implying maximum or minimum.

Comment: Could you, please, add an exemplary code snippet or pseudo code?